# Burgers' equation $u_t + uu_x =0$ with $u(x,0)=x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Solve Burgers' equation $$u_t + uu_x =0,$$ 
>   with $u=u(x,t)$ and the side condition $u(x,0)=x$.

I am not sure on how to find the solution $u(x,t)$. I have learned the method of characteristics. I am neither sure on how to use the side condition in Burgers' equation.

Comment: Google showed me the true way - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation

Comment: why don't you elaborate on your attempts?

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with? What do you know about PDEs?

Comment: i am not sure on how to find the solution U(x,t). I have learnt the method of characteristics.

Comment: I am too lazy to write the same thing twice, so [I'll just give you a link instead](https://williewong.wordpress.com/2010/10/28/shock-singularities-in-burgers-equation/).

Answer (score 10):

This PDE is called the (inviscid) Burgers' equation. The characteristic equations are the system of ODEs $${dx\over dt}=u, \quad {du\over dt}=0,$$ which has solution $$u=C_1, \quad x=ut+C_2,$$ where $C_1,C_2$ are constants. But $C_1$ is a function of $C_2$, so $$u=C_1\implies u=C_1(C_2)=C_1(x-ut).$$ To determine $C_1$, note that the side condition requires $$u(x,0)=C_1(x-u(x,0)\cdot 0)=x\implies C_1(x)=x.$$ Thus, $u=x-ut$ and we conclude $$u(x,t)={x\over 1+t}.$$

Comment: I saw and answered the newer version of this same question [here first.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306513/solve-the-following-partial-differential-equation-u-t-uu-x-0/306716#306716) Didn't know if I should attempt to close this one as a duplicate since it came first. I defer to others on the board as to how to handle this.

Comment: I voted to close the newer question as a duplicate of this one. You should feel free to vote to close as well, since you have 3K.

Comment: I was wondering how you can deal with this solution at t=-1? My lecturer suggested introducing a shock, but I have only met shocks in the context of data curves with discontinuities, and am not sure how to apply that here... Could you help?