# what is the Quasi Linear equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can anyone explain the Quasi Linear Equation

A first order PDE is called quasilinear if its coefficients depend on the variable u.

A example would help.

Comment: http://www.dm.unibo.it/home/citti/html/AnalisiMM/quasilinearfirstorder.pdf

Comment: I can't seem to find any quasi linear equations that i can solve. I have to know the Burgers Equation as well. Are they related?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had not seen it was first order.

Comment: From what I see in your link, they're related since the Burgers equation is an example of quasilinear first oder pde.

Comment: For example I have a burgers equation but i am not sure on how to solve it. I read wikipedia on how to solve burgers equation with a side condition but i had not achieved much.

Comment: What does everyone want to solve Burgers' equation these days? Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/306513/53153) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/305727/53153). You can read about quasilinear equations of 1st and 2nd order in the [notes by Erich Miersemann](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~miersemann/pdebook.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The definition you asked about works only in some specific cases, I think.

A quasi-linear equation, informally, is a PDE whose *highest order* terms appear only as *individual terms*, multiplied by lower order terms (I found this definition in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112841/difference-between-linear-semilinear-and-quasiliner-pdes) question).
So the Burgers' equation is a quasi-linear first-order PDE because you can write it as $$(1, u) \cdot (u_t, u_x)=0 .$$

A more specific definition of quasi-linear PDE is the following.
Let's first write a PDE in its general form: $$F(D^k(u), D^{k-1}(u), \ldots, Du, u, x) =0$$ where $x$ is in some open set $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $u: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown function and $F: \mathbb{R}^{n^k} \times \mathbb{R}^{n^{k-1}} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given.

[$D^k(u)$ stands for the $k$-th multi-index derivative of $u$. That's a generalized way to write a derivative of a scalar multi-variable function.]

A PDE is quasi-linear if you can write it as:
$$\sum_{|\alpha|=k} a_{\alpha} (D^{k-1} (u), \ldots, Du, u, x) D^{\alpha} (u) + a_0 (D^{k-1} (u), \ldots, Du, u, x) = 0.$$

Considering the Burgers' equation, we have $k=1$, $a_1 (Du, u, x) = (1, u)$ and $Du = (u_t, u_x)$. With a little bit of patience you can see that this extended definition actually works.

Source: L.C. Evans, *Partial Differential Equations* (2010), AMS

Comment: Woah, I didn't notice this question was posted 4 years ago! I think you have found your answers by now...