# Weak solution for Burgers' equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I have the following IVP:
$$
u_t + u u_x = 0,\qquad 
u(x,0) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &0.5 && \text{if } {-3}<x<-2 \\
   &1   && \text{if } {-2}<x<0 \\
   &1-x && \text{if } 0\leq x<1 \\
   &0   && \text{if } x\geq 1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Question is to find weak solution say at $t=1,2$

#### try

Well, the characteristics are given by

$$ \frac{dt}{ds} = 1, \frac{d x }{ds} = u, \frac{u}{ds} = 0 $$

and we choose the initial curve to be $(r,0,f(r))$ where $f(r) = u(r,0)$

We see that the characteristics are of the form $x= f(r) s +r $ and $t = s$

when trying to graph the characteristics, there at the endpoints of the intial data we have lines that cross but I dont understand how to find weak solution. what would be the strategy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, weak solutions are not unique. I guess that you rather want to find the entropy solution. Here is a plot of the characteristic curves in the $x$-$t$ plane, deduced from the method of characteristics:

[image: char]

In the vicinity of $x=-3$ and $x=-2$, characteristics separate. Hence, according to the Lax entropy condition, rarefaction waves are obtained. The entropy solution is smooth for small times $0<t < 1$ (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843118/418542) and related ones):
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &(x+3)/t  && \text{if } {-3}<x<-3+t/2 \\
   &1/2 && \text{if } {-3}+t/2<x<-2 + t/2 \\
   &(x+2)/t && \text{if } {-2} + t/2 <x<-2 + t \\
   &1   && \text{if } {-2}+t<x<t \\
   &(1-x)/(1-t) && \text{if } t\leq x<1 \\
   &0   && \text{if } x\geq 1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

At the time $t=1$, characteristic curves intersect (*breaking time*). To compute the solution for larger times, one must compute the shock wave starting at $(x,t)=(1,1)$ by using the Rankine-Hugoniot condition, which gives the shock speed $s = \frac{1}{2}(1 + 0) = 1/2$. Thus the solution for $1\leq t < t^*$ reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &(x+3)/t  && \text{if } {-3}<x<-3+t/2 \\
   &1/2 && \text{if } {-3}+t/2<x<-2 + t/2 \\
   &(x+2)/t && \text{if } {-2} + t/2 <x<-2 + t \\
   &1   && \text{if } {-2}+t<x<1+(t-1)/2 \\
   &0   && \text{if } x\geq 1+(t-1)/2
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

For larger times, one must consider the interaction between the shock wave and the rarefaction wave starting at $x=-2$, since the rarefaction moves faster than the shock. Both waves intersect at the time $t^*$ such that $-2 + t^* = 1+(t^*-1)/2$, i.e. $t^*=5$. The new shock has the speed $\dot x_s = \frac{1}{2}\left((x_s+2)/t + 0\right)$ deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. Since the interaction occurs at $x_s(t^*)=3$, we find $x_s(t) = \sqrt{5t}-2$. Thus, for $5\leq t < t^\dagger$, the solution reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &(x+3)/t  && \text{if } {-3}<x<-3+t/2 \\
   &1/2 && \text{if } {-3}+t/2<x<-2 + t/2 \\
   &(x+2)/t && \text{if } {-2} + t/2 <x<\sqrt{5t}-2 \\
   &0   && \text{if } x> \sqrt{5t}-2
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

For larger times, one must consider the interaction between the shock wave and the constant state $u=1/2$, since it moves faster than the shock. Both waves intersect at the time $t^\dagger$ such that $-2 + t^\dagger/2 = \sqrt{5t^\dagger}-2$, i.e. $t^\dagger=20$. The new shock has the speed $s = \frac{1}{2} (1/2 + 0)$ deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition, and we find $x_s(t) = 3+t/4$. Thus, for $20\leq t < t^\circ$, the solution reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &(x+3)/t  && \text{if } {-3}<x<-3+t/2 \\
   &1/2 && \text{if } {-3}+t/2<x<3+t/4 \\
   &0   && \text{if } x> 3+t/4
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
For larger times, one must consider the interaction between the shock wave and the rarefaction starting at $x=-3$, since it moves faster than the shock. Both waves intersect at the time $t^\dagger$ such that $-3+t^\circ/2 = 3+t^\circ/4$, i.e. $t^\circ=24$. The new shock has the speed $\dot x_s = \frac{1}{2} ((x_s+3)/t + 0)$ deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. Since the interaction occurs at $x_s(t^\circ)=9$, we find $x_s(t) = \sqrt{6t}-3$. Thus, for $24\leq t$, the solution reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
   &0 && \text{if } x<-3 \\
   &(x+3)/t  && \text{if } {-3}<x<\sqrt{6t}-3\\
   &0   && \text{if } x> \sqrt{6t}-3
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
The right edge of the wave has amplitude $\sqrt{6/t}$. Thus, its amplitude and propagation speed decrease with time.

Comment: What program did you use to plot the characteristics?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It is a homemade Maple script.

Comment: Hi, sorry for commenting here, but could you explain why you get $(x+3)/t$ for  $-3<x<-3+t/2$, instead of just $x/t$? Same with the $(x+2)/t$ part.

Comment: @Applesauce44 The rarefaction wave solution $x/t$ solves Riemann problems for initial discontinuities located at $x=0$. For an initial discontinuity at $x=x_0$ we get the solution $(x-x_0)/t$. Now set $x_0$ to -2 or -3.

Comment: @EditPiAf Ohh I see, thank you! I couldn't find any information on this anywhere I looked though, most solutions are for where $x=0$ is the initial discontinuity. If possible, could you suggest any place/book where this is explicitly stated?

Answer (score 1):

Since your initial data are discontinuous and also decreasing on part of the domain, your solution contains rarefaction waves and shock waves. The rarefaction waves appear at $x=-3$ and $x=-2$ at time $t=0$ and the shock appears at some positive time when the characteristics collide. To extend the solution beyond the collision you need the Rankine-Hugoniot conditions on the shock, giving you the right speed of the shock line. You can read about the topic here

https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/conservation.pdf