# Entropy solution of the inviscid Burgers' equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy

I have this exercise that asks me to find the entropy solution for the inviscid Burgers' equation ($\partial_t u+u~\partial_x u=0$) with initial condition

$u(x,0)=u_0(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if }\quad x<0, \\
       1 &\quad\text{if}\quad 0\leq x\leq 1, \\
       2 &\quad\text{if }\quad 1<x\leq 2,\\
       0 &\quad\text{if} \quad x>2\\ 
     \end{cases}
$

I see I should use Rankine Hugoniot condition and so I did and found that the discontinuity should be for $x=t/2,x=t, x=3/2t$. How can I find the proper solution?
Is that an entropy solution? How do I check it? I have seen there are similar questions but my issue is about entropy solution. Moreover I know nothing about shocks and they are often cited and used. Thanks

Comment: Burgers' with or without the viscosity term?

Comment: It's without...

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070821) deals with a very similar problem. Following the steps therein as well as in related posts should help.