# How do you find the t* where the shock wave collide with the rarefaction one?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

For the equation:

$\partial_t u + \partial_x(\frac{u^2} 2)$ = 0

with the initial condtions: 
$$
u(x,0) = g(x) = \begin{cases} 
2, \quad \text{si}  \quad x<1 \\
1,\quad \text{si}  \quad  1<x<2\\
2, \quad \text{si} \quad  x>2 \\
\end{cases}
$$

The characteristic equation is 
$$
x(t) = \xi + q'(g(\xi))t = \xi + g(\xi)t = \begin{cases}
\xi + 2t, \quad \text{si} \quad \xi \leq1  \\
\xi + t, \quad \text{si} \quad 1<\xi<2 \\ 
\xi + 2t, \quad \text{si} \quad \xi>2 \end{cases}
$$

There should one shock wave going from (1;0) and a refaction one on (2;0)

a) Shock wave (1,0)

$$
\begin{cases}
s'(t) = \frac{q(u_R) - q(u_L)}{u_R-u_L} = \frac{(u_R+u_L)}{2} =  \frac{(2+1)}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \\
s(0) = 1
\end{cases}
\implies x = s(t) = \frac{3}{2}t + 1
$$

b) Rarefaction wave $(2,0)$ between $x(t) = 1+t$ and $x(t) = 1+2t$

$$
u(x,t) = (q')^{-1}\left(\frac{x-1}{t}\right) = \frac{x-2}{t} \\
$$
Can't find the intersection (x*,t*)

Comment: So the boundary of the rarefaction are x = 2 + t and 2+2t instead of x=1+t and 1+2t?

Comment: Thanks, everything is good now i know the right boundaries

Answer (score 1):

Note that the rarefaction is continuous at its boundaries. Thus, one boundary of the rarefaction is incorrect. You actually need to find when the shock trajectory $x=s(t)=1+\frac32 t$ intersects the boundary $x={\color{red}2}+t$ of the rarefaction. A plot of the characteristic lines might help (see this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843118/418542)).