# Burgers equation with method of characteristic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

This question is example 1 page 139 Evans PDE book 2nd edition.

Consider the initial value problem:

\begin{cases}
u_t+\left(\frac{u^2}{2} \right)_x =0 & \text{in }\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty) \\
\qquad \qquad \, \, u=g & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times\{t=0\}
\end{cases}

with $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x \leq 0 \\
1-x & \text{if }0 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{if }x \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Now using method of characteristic, we get the IVP:
$\frac{dX}{dt}=u(X(t),t)$
$X(0)=x_0$ and we can show that $u$ is constant along the curve $X(t) = x_0 + g(x_0)t$. Given fixed $(x,t)$, the solution is $u(x_0)$, where $x_0$ is a function of $(x,t)$. In that example, all the steps are skipped and we arrive at the following solution for $t \leq 1$

$$u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x \leq t \text{ , } t \leq 1 \\
\frac{1-x}{1-t} & \text{if }t \le x \le 1 \text{ , } t \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{if }x \geq 1 \text{ , } t \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

Can someone help me fill in the blank here, as how to find $x_0$ as a function of $(x,t)$ and arrive at the function $u$ below?

Comment: This question is asked *often* here. Did you try searching the site?

Comment: Almost the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843118/method-of-characteristics-for-burgers-equation-with-rectangular-data?noredirect=1)