# Is this shock/rarefaction problem solved correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

So I'm coursing a subject in PDE and the theory for these kind of problems is quite scarce, and I don't seem to find many solved problems online. The problem is stated as follows:

**Analyse the following shock-fitting problem. Draw the solution u(x, t) for several times.**

\begin{equation}
 \begin{cases}
  u_t + uu_x = 0, & t>0, \ \ x\in \mathbb{R} \\
  u(x, 0) =
   \begin{cases}
     1, \\
    -1, \\
     0, 
   \end{cases}
   & 
   \begin{aligned}
    x < 0 \\
    0 < x < 1 \\
    x> 1
   \end{aligned}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Notation: The equation can be written as $u_t + c(u)u_x = 0$ where $c(u) = u$.

***Solution:***

Let $\Phi(x) := u(x,0)$. We can rewrite the system as:

\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{dt} = U, & X(0) = \xi \\
\frac{dU}{dt} = 0, & U(0) = \phi(\xi)
\end{cases}

From here, we see that

\begin{equation}
U(t) = U(0) = \Phi(\xi) = 
\begin{cases} 
1, &  \xi < 0 \\
-1, & 0 < \xi < 1 \\
0, & \xi > 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

So, it's easy to figure out

\begin{equation}
X'(t) = \Phi(\xi) \Rightarrow X(t) = \Phi(\xi)t + \xi = 
\begin{cases} 
2t + \xi, &  \xi < 0 \\
-2t + \xi, & 0 < \xi < 1 \\
\xi, & \xi > 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now, the case for $\xi = 0$. We introduce the flux $q$ and identify $q'(u) = c(u) = u$, so $q(u) = \frac{u^2}{2}. We then can find the shock wave

\begin{equation}
 \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{[q]}{[u]} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1^2-(-1)^2}{1-(-1)} = 0 \Rightarrow s(t) = 0
\end{equation}

For the case $\xi = 1$

\begin{equation}
 c(u) = c^{-1}(u) = u \Rightarrow u(x,t) = \frac{x-1}{t}
\end{equation}

The final solution then would be

\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x<0 \\
-1, & 0<x<1 \\
\frac{x-1}{t}, & 1<x<t \\
0, & x \geq t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I feel very insecure about this answer. If it is indeed right, I'd also appreciate to know *why*. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Also, are there any resources where I can learn about this kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce the notation $q(u) = \frac12 u^2$ for the physical flux such that $c(u) = q'(u)$ defines the transport velocity. The static shock wave with speed $s'(t) = 0$ starting at $x=0$ is computed correctly. However, the proposed rarefaction wave solution starting at $x=1$ is incorrect (note that the solution is discontinuous, and that it is undefined for small times due to the domain condition $1< x< t$). The solution should read as follows:
$$
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
1, & x< 0, \\
-1, & 0< x < 1-t ,\\
\tfrac{x-1}{t}, & 1-t< x< 1 ,\\
0, & 1< x .
\end{cases}
$$
Note that this solution is only valid for small times $t<1$ where the shock interacts with the rarefaction. You can read more about wave interactions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843118/418542), and about Riemann problems [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157585/418542).

Comment: Didn't think I would have an answer to this question. Thanks! This is very thorough