# Inviscid Burgers' equation: drawing the shock

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Solve Burgers' equation
> $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned}
> u_{t}+uu_x &=0 \quad \text { for } \quad t>0 \\
> u(x, 0) &=u_{0}(x)
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
> with $u=u(x,t)$ and the side condition $u(x,0)=-x$.

I am aware that a similar question with [initial condition u=x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305727/solve-burgers-equation) has been asked before, and asked this because I was wondering what the difference would be when the characteristic lines are set to converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From implicit function theorem we have the following

$$u_t+uu_x = 0 \implies \frac{dx}{dt}=u$$

So in other words, the slopes of the characteristics depend on the value of $u$. With $u=x$, you can see that the characteristics that start at negative $x$ move left (negative slope) and vice versa for positive $x$. Could you reason out the behavior for $u=-x$ instead?

Bonus question, technically the shock in both situations could be chosen to be anything, but how does one pick out the max entropy solution for both $u=x$ and $u=-x$ ?

Comment: Did you mean to write $u = dx/dt$?

Comment: @SallyG You're absolutely right! Let me fix that

Comment: Thanks, is my guess correct, too?

Comment: @SallyG Interesting, I usually don't solve the Burgers equation explicitly but that solution checks out. What happens to the characteristics when they intersect $x=0$ ?

Comment: I'm new to this topic, so I'm not sure. Maybe this is where the sonic-wave-shock happens?

Comment: For the max entropy solution (the physical one where all the characteristics move at the same time) the characteristics will terminate at the $x=0$ line. That is called a shock.

Comment: I see. Learned a lot of vocab today. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116854/discussion-between-sally-g-and-ninad-munshi).