# Characteristics for Burgers equation with $u(x,0)=x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics

In the $(x,t)$- plane, the characteristic of the initial value problem $$u_t+uu_x=0$$ with $$u(x,0)=x,0\leq x\leq 1$$ are

$1$. parallel straight lines .

$2.$ straight lines which intersects at $(0,-1)$.

$3.$ non- intersecting parabolas.

$4.$ concentric circles with center at origin.

I am learning partial differential equation so don’t have good knowledge of it . According to me characteristic equations are

$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{0}$$ Now $u=c$ by last fraction. So by first two fractions I have $x-ct=k$, where $c$ and $k$ are constants. Now I don’t known how to use initial condition of $u(x,0)=x$ and what is final answer? I see that $x-ct-k=0$ are straight lines in $(x,t)$-plane. Please help me to reach at final option . Thank you.

Comment: I am confused by the "characteristic equation" you've stated, what does $\frac{du}0$ represent? also you have stated the domain of $x$ but are there any restrictions on t? normally $t\ge 0$

Comment: @HenryLee I have written the question exactly. Yes there may be mistake I had as I am not good in PDE.

Comment: @HenryLee Writing $\frac{du}{0}$ in this context just implies $u$ is constant in some variable. It isn't literal division by zero.

Comment: @neelkanth You found the characteristics $u = C_{2}$ and $x - ut = C_{1}$, hence the solution to the PDE is given implicitly by $$u = f(x-ut)$$ Applying the IC gives $x = u(x,0) = f(x - u(x,0) \cdot 0) = f(x)$ and hence the explicit solution is $$u = x - ut \implies u = \frac{x}{1+t}$$

Comment: @mattos so what is answer ??

Comment: @mattos sir question is not about solutions. It’s about characteristics . I am confused about that .

Comment: 'Now I don’t known how to use initial condition of $u(x,0) = x$ and what is final answer?' Seems to me you asked about the solution. Anyway, you have the characteristics. Do you think they look like parabolas? Or concentric circles?

Comment: @mattos  seems to be straight lines but how to use initial condition to answer option $1$ or option $2$?

Comment: @mattos final answer according to me means final option to be correct.

Comment: @mattos as I get $x-C_2t=C_1$ but here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants, so what will be answer from first two options ?

Comment: @neelkanth Please don't tag me in a comment in order to get me to look at your other questions.

Comment: Sorry for that sir .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of the initial value problem is discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305727/418542). So we end up with the set of curves
$$
u=C_1, \qquad x-ut=C_2
$$
where $C_1$, $C_2$ are constants. These curves are straight lines in the $x$-$t$ plane, thus options 3. and 4. are eliminated. Now we implement the boundary condition $u(x,0)=x$ at $t=0$:
$$
x=C_1, \qquad x-x\cdot 0 = C_2 ,
$$
i.e. $C_1=C_2=c$.
To see if the curves $x-ct=c$ are parallel, we look at the slope in $x$-$t$ coordinates, whose value equals $$c=u = \frac{x}{1+t}.$$
Are these curves parallel? Lastly you could check for the intersection of two characteristics by solving the system
$$
x-a t = a, \qquad x-b t = b
$$
with respect to $(x,t)$ for $0\leq a\neq b \leq 1$.

Comment: thank you very much sir .... you give exactly what I was wanted .

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to expand on my comment. This appears to fit the form of the [Inviscid Burgers' equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation#Inviscid_Burgers%27_equation) which is:
$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$$
Using the method of characteristics we say:
$$u(x,t)=u(x(s),t(s))$$
then assume:
$$\frac d{ds}u(x(s),t(s))=F(u,x(s),t(s))$$
and using chain rule we get:
$$\frac d{ds}u(x(s),t(s))=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{ds}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{ds}$$

---

I am not not particularly versed in this method but I hope this information helped

Comment: I have to select from options .

Comment: @Henery Lee as I get $x-C_2t=C_1$ but here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants, so what will be answer from first two options ?